# Php loop through Json Objects and arra

Tags: php, json

hi want to loop through json below how can i do this using php

```
{
values: [
{
   nameValuePairs: {
   address: "0111",
   body: "Transaction cost, Ksh28.00.",
   date: "1571473093291",
}
},
{
   nameValuePairs: {
   address: "0101",
   body: "Transaction cost, Ksh0.00.",
   date: "1498823347530",
  }
  },
]
}
```

need the values of  address,body and date in a foreach loop
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert `json` to `array` by using `json_decode` and loop through the array

```
 $a =  json_decode($json, true);
```

Use Loop

```
 foreach($a['values'] as $v){
  echo $v['nameValuePairs']['address']."\n";
  echo $v['nameValuePairs']['body']."\n";
  echo $v['nameValuePairs']['date']."\n";
 }
```

See demo here : https://3v4l.org/QC06g

Comment: i alredy tried this  $a =  json_decode($json, true); foreach($a  as $row){
  $row["address"]
} not getting result

Comment: @Fredmax you should have valid json format, check the link

Comment: Hi @Rakesh thank you for your response, i was able to get result as per your link https://3v4l.org/IdrZk, kindly how do i loop through to get values of address,body and date i tried foreach($new_array as $row )
{
    echo $row["address"];
}

Comment: @Fredmax here https://3v4l.org/QC06g, all the information iteration

Comment: @RakeshJakhar please [edit] your answer to include what you have in the comments.